# IPAD lost with Ripple wallet

Tags: wallet

Lost my Ipad with Toast ripple wallet. I have wallet address, recovery keys and phrase. Can I create a new wallet and send the coins from old to new?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to send the coins anywhere. Just recreate the old wallet with the recovery phrase.

Digital assets aren't literally in wallets. Wallets just hold the keys necessary to access to assets.

Comment: David, does ripple still use the secp256k1 curve, I heard that there were plans to change it? Ripple uses an account based model, so you would also not suggest using BIP32 with it right?

Comment: You can use secp256k1 keys if you want. You can also use Ed25519 keys. It may be wise to move the funds (or re-key the account) if you're worried about someone extracting the keys from the lost device. You can use deterministic key generation schemes if you wish.